Exclude Section From Every Page From LiteSpeed Cache
I have a header that includes an image & textual information that changes depending on a weekly schedule (that changes quite often).
If I use LiteSpeed cache, the image and textual information get's cached, and shows the two at incorrect times, as the processing PHP code to determine exactly which image and data gets shown, isn't having an affect.
Is there any way to utilise LiteSpeed cache without it affecting this portion of the page/functionality of the site?
Thanks.
